# get the attachement url for the medium sized image

Tags: images

Hi I'm using some code to create a slideshow with lytebox functionality - the following code is used in the loop to pull each image attached to a post in sequence.

It seems to be only pulling the large image, even thought I've set the value to medium - any ideas how I can get .wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'medium', false, false)  to be pulling the medium sized images?

thanks

```
                                <?php
$argsThumb = array(
'order'          => 'DESC',
'post_type'      => 'attachment',
'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'post_status'    => null
);
$attachments = get_posts($argsThumb);
if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
echo '<div class="images"><a class="lytebox" href="' .wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'medium', false, false). '"><img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'medium', false, false).'" /><div class="caption">'.apply_filters('the_content', $attachment->post_content).'</div></a></div>';
}
```

}

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`wp_get_attachment_url()` will only return url to original attachment file, this function only accepts attachment id as parameter.

Use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) or [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) instead.

Comment: neither of those seem to return the url though do they?

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_src()` returns array and first parameter is image url. See linked codex page for more details.

Comment: Update for those finding this all these years later. The function you want is called ``wp_get_attachment_image_url()``.

All you need to do is give it the attachment ID and the size and it will return either a string of the image url or false.

Answer (score 12):

echo out the following: `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->ID, 'medium')[0];` to the attachment url for the medium sized image.

Comment: _Function array dereferencing_ is a PHP 5.4+ feature. Not that this should be a problem. Just to let anyone know.

Comment: Update for those finding this all these years later. The function you want is called wp_get_attachment_image_url().

All you need to do is give it the attachment ID and the size and it will return either a string of the image url or false.

Answer (score 2):

Update for those finding this all these years later. The function you want is called `wp_get_attachment_image_url()`. [Documentation here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/).

All you need to do is give it the attachment ID and the size and it will return either a string of the image url or false.

Answer (score 1):

I don't how above answer makes the answer. 
`wp_get_attachment_image_src` need attachment id not post id.
`<?php echo esc_url((wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_id()), 'medium')[0])?>`