# get_thumbnail_id returns full size image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want a thumbnail of the featured image of the posts as a URL. So I'm using the following code to get a smaller size of the featured image.

```
$post[$i]['thumbnail'] = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post[$i]['id'], 'thumbnail'));
```

However all the time it returns the full size image, I even tried,

```
 $post[$i]['thumbnail'] = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post[$i]['id'], array(120,140)));
```

But still it returns the large image. How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45033/get-the-attachement-url-for-the-medium-sized-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey First add this line into your function.php file

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 120, 140 );
```

Then call custom-size like this

```
<?php $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $id );
                if ( '' != $thumb_id ) {
                    $thumb_url  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'custom-size', true );
                    $image      = $thumb_url[0];
                }?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image;?>">
```

I think it work fine

Comment: but what is 'thumbnail' is also returning the full size of the image? not a thumbnail size?

Comment: hey thumbnail  size is define in wordpress admin panel settings->media->Thumbnail-size please check it what size define in media for thumbnail

Comment: @amrith it's set to the default 150x150 but i'm not retrieving that i'm getting the full size of it

Comment: hey rksh please check the edited answer its work for me

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post[$i]['id']);
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail', true);
$post[$i]['thumbnail'] = $thumb_url_array[0];
```

In the above code,  `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` returns an array with image src, height and width, `$thumb_url_array[0]` is your thumbnail.

Comment: much prefer this solution as it can be used outside of a theme file

Answer (score 1):

The Syntax is defined as

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?>
```

You can get default wordpress thumbnail size (150X150) by following code

```
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
```

If you want a custom size thumbnail, then use bellow code :

```
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array( 200, 200) ); ?>
```

For further reference visit wordpress codex [Click Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)