# Get a specific size from wp_get_attachment_image_src

Tags: loop, images

I have this section in my website where i use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to get all the images associated with the post, but now you want to get a certain size (size: listing_grid):

```
 <?php  $args = array(
            'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'numberposts'    => 15, // -1, show all
            'post_status'    => 'any',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
            'order'           => 'ASC'
       );

$images = get_posts($args);
if($images) { ?>


<images>
    <?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
    <image><![CDATA[<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID); ?>]]></image>
    <?php } ?>
</images>   
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: use get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $image->ID, 'full' ), instead of wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID ); and see if this works

Comment: this might help you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45033/get-the-attachement-url-for-the-medium-sized-image

Comment: the first solution does not work, but I'll see if I get something in the second option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks maverick, your solution works

```
<?php  $args = array(
            'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'numberposts'    => 15, // -1, show all
            'post_status'    => 'any',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
            'order'           => 'ASC'
       );

$images = get_posts($args);
if($images) { ?>


<images>
    <?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
    <image><![CDATA[<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'listing_gallery_2x')[0]; ?>]]></image>
    <?php } ?>
</images>   
<?php } ?>
```